# What does the sed command in the line below do?

Tags: sed

I was analyzing the script file and I came across the line below

```
sed -i '/JBOSS_HOME\/bin\/run.sh/i \export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp ' /home/jboss/runJBOSSEAP.sh
```

I am still not able to figure out what does this command do. I know `-i` means it is an inline operation. But what it does is still unknown to me. Please help me understand this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -i
```

`-i` says to edit file in-place, that is write the new version over the same name

```
/JBOSS_HOME\/bin\/run.sh/
```

A pattern, separated by slashes, the slashes contained in the pattern are quoted with backslashes, so this matches any line containing `JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh`. (Actually since it's a regex, the dot matches any character.)

```
i \export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp '
```

Command to run when the pattern matches, `i` is for inserting a line (before the current). The line to be added is separated by the backslash, so this adds the string `export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp`.

```
/home/jboss/runJBOSSEAP.sh
```

Target file name.

e.g.

```
$ echo JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh > pla 
$ sed -i '/JBOSS_HOME\/bin\/run.sh/i \export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp ' pla
$ cat pla
export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp 
JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh
```

It's pretty much the same as e.g. the example [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-41)

Answer (score 1):

ilkkachu's answer is great and extensive, upvote given. Here's just a side note if you are using BSD sed (as in OS X). This:

```
sed -i '/JBOSS_HOME\/bin\/run.sh/i \export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp ' foo 
sed: 1: "foo": invalid command code f
```

Does not work. In order for it to work with BSD sed you first need to fix the `-i` option like this: `sed -i.""`. Furthermore, you need to have your insert on a separate line, like this:

```
sed -i."" '/JBOSS_HOME\/bin\/run.sh/i \
export TMP_FOLDER=$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/tmp ' foo
```

But, again, this is just if you are using BSD sed as found under OS X. Does not apply to GNU sed.